# How to create videocall Layout like whatsapp for android native layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]
I wish to make a very nice videocall design like whatsapp,where on clicking video call floating action button ,it just appear video and on ending call it just disappear.  something like below image . Since i am not good in android native layout design, i would highly appreciate for a design help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `ConstraintLayout`. Almost like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_speakerphone"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/bright_blue"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_more"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/bright_blue"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/hangoutButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_call_incoming"
        android:backgroundTint="#ff0000"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="04:20"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/hangoutButton"
        android:background="#60000000"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output as follows:

[image: whatsapp like video call]